# Import a library struct in tests suite

Tags: rust

i'm trying to acces a struct from the lib i'm creating to perform some unit tests.

here is a sample of the code:

src/token_deserializer.rs

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Token {
    pub payment_data: PaymentData,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct PaymentData {
    pub data: String,
    pub signature: String,
    pub header: String,
    pub version: String,
}
```

src/lib.rs

```rust
use serde_json::from_str;
use token_deserializer::Token;
pub mod token_deserializer;

pub fn deserialize_token(token: &str) -> Token{
    let object: Token = from_str(token).expect("JSON was not well-formatted");
    return object;
}
```

tests/mytest.rs

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::fs::File;
    use apple_pay_token_decryptor::deserialize_token;
    use apple_pay_token_decryptor::Token;

    #[test]
    fn test_token_deserialization(){
        let mut file = File::open("text.json").unwrap();
        let mut data = String::new();
        let object: Token = deserialize_token(&data);
    }
}
```

Here i can't manage to import Token for my test => `` error[E0603]: struct `Token` is private ``

Do i need to import it in lib.rs or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your test, you refer to `apple_pay_token_decryptor::Token`. You may think it is resolved to the `pub struct Token`, but in fact, it is not. Instead, it refers to this `use` in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
use token_deserializer::Token;
```

And while both the struct and the `token_deserializer` module are public - this import is private (it is not `pub use`, i.e. a reexport). But it's still there. And thus the compiler complains about you using a private type.

To fix, that you either have to reexport `Token` - i.e. make that `pub use token_deserializer::Token;`, or fix the test to import the struct directly from `token_deserializer`:

```rust
use apple_pay_token_decryptor::token_deserializer::Token;
```